# JQuery: can't re-update links (I'm new to JQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to Jquery and I'm getting crazy to reupdate in ajax a code containing urls!!
It works the first time, but the link does not work any longer after ajax response rewrites html.

Please, find below my code.

First the HTML markup (View)

```
<head>  
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">  
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("a[class=unselected_quid], a[class=quid_selected]").click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr("name");
        alert(url);
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php", 
            type: "POST",  
            data: url,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(msg) {    
                $("#result").html(msg);  
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("error!!!");
            } 
        });
    });
  });
</script>  
</head> 

<?php // set url strings in php
  $url = "component=Training&ctrl=JQueryTraining&task=ajaxLinkResponse&data=1";
  $url2 = "component=Training&ctrl=JQueryTraining&task=ajaxLinkResponse&data=2";
?>

<body>  
  <div id="result"><br>
    <a name='<?echo $url?>' href='javascript:void(0)' title='uno' class='selected_quid'>link a</a> <br>
    <a name='<?echo $url2?>' href='javascript:void(0)' title='due' class='unselected_quid'>link b</a><br>
  </div>  
</body>
```

Then the PHP (Controller)

```
public function ajaxLinkResponse(){
  $url = "component=Training&ctrl=JQueryTraining&task=ajaxLinkResponse&data=1";
  $url2 = "component=Training&ctrl=JQueryTraining&task=ajaxLinkResponse&data=2";

  $code = "<a name='{<?$url?>}' href='javascript:void(0)' title='uno' class='selected_quid'>link a</a> 
  <a name='{<?$url2?>}' href='javascript:void(0)' title='due' class='unselected_quid'>link b</a>";  

  echo($code);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`.live()`](http://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Flive%2F&ei=UWgJTZqkDYTevQPO9JzgBQ&usg=AFQjCNHPnKvzKaTw54m1H-YHMmd8NEWjTQ&sig2=QhSr-78X4wnJeUGETCAxTQ) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of `.click()` as you are making new DOM elements in your AJAX call and `.click()` does not cater for DOM element creation.
i.e.

```
$("a[class=unselected_quid], a[class=quid_selected]").live('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
// rest of code
```

or

```
$(aWrapper).delegate('a[class=unselected_quid], a[class=quid_selected]','click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
// rest of code
```

You may ask 'What's the difference?' well [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-the-difference-between-live-and-delegate/) should help.
Basically delegate is faster, will not crash with heavy DOM traversals, and you can supply a context (this is a big feature).

Comment: @Fred - +1 for the info on delegate. I haven't seen that before. Are there any disadvantages to delegate?

Comment: @JasCav Not that I know of, it's only just recently come out (in 1.4.4 I think). Have you heard of `.data()`? It's REALLY handy.

Comment: @Fred - I actually just learned of .data() in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433869/handling-keyboard-in-drop-down-list). Extremely helpful!

Comment: @Fred: thank you for your help Fred. I did not know this behavior! However, I tried the .live option and it works, the .delegate one does not. Do I need to keep the document ready line too?

Comment: Yup, you do. The delegate one is a bit more complex as it needs a _context_ (something to search within). This is _not_ the same as $('aWrapper a').live() as that is just a different selector.  This is why I use `aWrapper`, so if you have an element which encompasses all of the links, change `aWrapper` to that.

Comment: P.S. Can you mark this as a correct solution (i.e. tick it)? Please?